# How to log process that accesses disk for longer than 5 seconds continously?

Tags: disk-usage, disk

Sometimes disk spins up when computer is inactive and it lasts and lasts and lasts. I have no idea how to figure out what it is.

Usually I notice this while lying down and by the time I get there and start iotop it's gone. It feels like I am using windows and my data is just being read from the disk without my permission and sent God knows where.

I have atop installed but I have no idea how to use it for this user case.
`atop -d` shows data in real time and doesn't filter it for long continuous use.